# SSMS 2016 - Text Editor Color Settings

Tags: t-sql, colors, text-editor, ssms-2016

Anyone could help me to restore default text editor color settings in SSMS 2016?

[query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86aLY.png)

Might it to depend from the fact that "the menu is in Italian and the buttons are in English"? (sorry for the simplification).

Infact, first of all I have run SSMS-Setup-ITA.exe and then SSMS-Setup-ENU.exe.

I click on "Use default" button but it seems not working.
Thank you in advance for your replies.

[SQL String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR2Nu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your sample image shows a SQL statement. So you should use the formatting for SQL String (SQL Stringa) in stead of String. That should work.

Comment: The SQL string formatting seems not work (see the modified image).

Answer (score 0):

Ribbon **Window** -> **reset window layout**.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I click on Reset Window Layout but the "SQL String" text color is still black.

Comment: :O Imposible. Your SQL String it's not important - it's text editor. So try please Environment->fonts and colors -> text editor -> use defaults.

Comment: [Reset Window Layout](http://imgur.com/a/SsP6b)

and

[getdate() is still black](http://imgur.com/a/KggUt)